# Is it possible to pass Ajax response as template context variable in Django?

Tags: python, django, ajax

I sent an Ajax request to server to get some filtered data and here is a sample I receive from server:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, title: "12 Rue Longueil", slug: "12-rue-longueil", latitude: null, longitude: null, …}
1: {id: 2, title: "15 Rue Sherbrooke LM", slug: "15-rue-sherbrooke-lm", latitude: null, longitude: null, …}
2: {id: 3, title: "Cycle Neron", slug: "cycle-neron", latitude: "-73.5987000000000000", longitude: "45.4799000000000000", …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

above data is logged from console.

I want to display these data in HTMl tags within cards below.

[image]

but for that I need to use that received data and create children using JavaScript e.g. `document.createElement('DIV')`. and then place these data.

```
  $(document).on('submit', "#filterform", function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{% url 'listing:search' %}",
            data: {
                listing_for: $('#listing_for').val(),
                // cutted
            },

            success: function (response) {
                const listings = eval(response);
    
                const content = document.getElementById('content');

                for (let i = 0; i < listings.length; i++) {
                    const div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.className = 'listing mgb-1';
                    div.innerHTML = data[i].title;
                    content.appendChild(div);

                    // have to create, add lots of divs and classes
                }

            }
        })
    })
```

I was wondering if there is a way to sent Ajax request data as template variable? Or do I have to hardcode all HTML tags using Javascript?

Edit: Edited content based on first answer creating a separate HTML.

```
def search(request):
    ...
    lst = list()

    for listing in queryset:
        ser = ListingSerializer(listing)
        lst.append(ser.data)
    
    return render(request, 'listing/newHtmlFile.html', {'listings': json.dumps(lst)})
```

separate HTML:

```
{% for list in listings %}
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>{{ list.title }}</h1>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

and ajax request:

```
success: function (response) {
    document.querySelector('#content').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', response);
}
```

Comment: not sure how response, listings, and data are related in the success function...

Comment: I am not sure, but aren't the sent response from server being handled in success function

Comment: certainly, however, you don't seem to be doing anything with the response, instead you're iterating over a variable named `data` that is not defined anywhere...

Comment: Just edited the answer, i had to iterate over `response` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Basically the idea is to make a separate HTML file that's going to be rendered by the view that handles the AJAX request. Then, you can use JavaScript and the `insertAdjacentHTML()` function to insert it in your original HTML file.

Take a look at this example:

**view:**

```py
def ajax_handler(request):
    # ... logic
    return render(request, 'newHtmlFile.html', {'your_context': data})
```

**Original HTML file**

```html
<div id='container'>
    
</div>
```

**newHtmlFile.html**

```html
<p>{{ your_context }}</p>
```

**JavaScript part** (*in this example I use Vanilla, not JQuery*)

```js
let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState === 4){
        if (this.status === 200){
            document.querySelector('#container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.responseText);
        }
    }
}
ajax.open('GET', '/ajax-handler-url', true);
ajax.send();
```

---

If you are interested to know how this works, we can break it down as follows:

1. You have some data (like a queryset, in your case) in your view
2. You call the `render()` method and you pass that data as the context data to a template
3. The `render()` method what actually does is to (let me be redundant here) render a HTML file (combining the HTML itself with the context data you passed) and return a `HTTPResponse` object containing a rendered text.
4. That rendered text (which is a bytestring that represents the content of the rendered HTML) is given as a response to the client. In this case, it's given specifically to the `$.ajax()` function that made the request.
5. We use the `insertAdjacentHTML()` function to append that rendered text to the desired element (in the example above, the `#container` div).

Comment: can you kindly take a look to updated answer. what I am doing wrong there

Comment: kindly check my updated answer, what I am doing wrong that I didn't get the expected output

Comment: Instead of passing a JSON formatted string (`json.dumps(lst)`), pass the list object (`lst`). Your context data should be: `{'listings': lst}`

Comment: yes, this solution is awesome and I need your help here `<a href="{{ list.get_absolute_url }}" >View Details</a>`  and `img src="{{ list.thumbnail.url }}"  >` doesn't work. when I inspect it it shows `<a href>View Details</a>` and when I inspect image it shows `<img src=(unknown)>`. Just  this please.

Comment: Hmm it's hard to tell with such a little info about the content of that `listings` list, but I would say that you should pass the queryset (`queryset`) that you have there in your view, rather than that list to the template, since it seems like you're trying to access to some model's methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216354/discussion-between-basir-payenda-and-revliscano).

Answer (score 1):

A quick, and possibly "dirty", way of doing it is to use the backtick strings in javascript:

```
success: function (r) {
    const listings = JSON.parse(r);  // with the correct headers from django, this should't be needed.
    listings.forEach(e => $('#content').append(`
        <div class="listing mgb-1">${e.title}</div>
    `));
}
```

You should return your data from django with the appropriate headers so you automatically get json and don't need to `eval(response)`.

Comment: you'll have to figure out what data is (perhaps it should just be `r.forEach(...)`, ie.iterating over the response from django.

Comment: I made a typo there, I was supposed to iterate over `listings` variable

Comment: can you kindly say why you call it a `dirty` solution while using template literal?

Comment: I suppose it isn't especially dirty. Constructing html by string concatenation is usually frowned upon because it's relatively slow and very ugly (hard to read).  Template literals don't suffer from either of those issues, so they're probably quite OK and it was just a historic knee-jerk reaction from me ;-)

Comment: need your help here, how do I handle this: `<a href="{% url 'listing:wishlist' ${list.slug} %}">Add to wishlist</a>` it is throwing error `Could not parse the remainder: '${list.slug}' from '${list.slug}'`

Comment: Template tags are evaluated by django _before_ it sends the resulting html to the browser. I.e. you cannot use django template tags from javascript. You _can_ use `reverse('listing:wishlist')` in django and pass the resulting url as part of the json response.