# Implement jQuery in a slider that uses dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, ajax

I am trying to add a slider with dynamic data to my django project using jQuery and ajax to do it, I received help to make the previous and next button which gives the ability to swipe through profiles, but I am now focusing on the previous one, in the process I realized that there is a NoReverseMatch error in the code and I don't know how to fix them because I am very new at jQuery and ajax.

views.py

```
    def matesmain(request):
        contents = Mates.objects.all()
        context = {
            'contents': contents,
            'form_mates': MatesForm(),
        }
        print("nice3")
        return render(request, 'mates.html', context)

    def previous(request):
        id= request.GET.get("id", None)
        if id != 1:
            previous_id= id-1
            prev_user= Mates.objects.filter(user= previous_id)
        data={ 
            "username": prev_user.user,
            "req_bio": prev_user.req_bio,
            "req_image": prev_user.req_image,
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

models.py

```
     class Mates(models.Model):
         user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usermates')
         users_requests = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="users_requests")
         req_bio = models.CharField(max_length=400)
         req_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='requestmates_pics', null=True, blank=True, default=False)

    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True, default='default.png')
        bio = models.CharField(max_length=400, default=1, null=True)
        connection = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
        follower = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        following = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('mates', views.mates, name='mates'),
        path('mates-main', views.matesmain, name='mates-main'),
        path('previous', views.previous, name='previous'),
    ]
```

html

```
    <div class="mates-grid-1-1-content">
        <div class="mates-grid-2-content">
            <button type="button"  onclick="previous({{user.id}})" id="prev-button">prev</button>
        </div>
        <div class="mates-grid-1-content">
            <div class="mates-item-content">
                <img class="mate-pic" src="{{ user.profile.profile_pic.url }}" >
            </div>
            <div class="mates-item-content">
                <a href="{% url 'profile' username=content.user.username %}" style="float: left">{{ content.user }}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="mates-item-content">
                <div class="responses">
                    <div class="response-item-img">
                        <img class="mates-image" src="{{ content.req_image.url }}" width="400px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="response-item-bio">
                        <p>{{ content.req_bio }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="response-item-button">
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mates-grid-3-content">
            <button type="button"  onclick="next({{user.id}})" id="next-button">next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

script

```
    function previous(id){
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'previous' %}',
            type: "get",
            data: {
                'id': id,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

            $(".mates-item-content").empty();
            $(".mates-item-content").append("<img class="mate-pic" src="{{ user.profile.profile_pic.url }}" >");
            $(".mates-item-content").empty();
            $(".mates-item-content").append("<a href="{% url 'profile' username=content.user.username %}" style="float: left">{{ content.user }}</a>");
            $(".mates-item-content").empty();
            $(".mates-item-content").append("<img class="mates-image" src="{{ content.req_image.url }}" width="400px">");
            $(".mates-item-content").empty();
            $(".mates-item-content").append("<p>{{ content.req_bio }}</p>");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('nope');
            }
          });
        }; 
    }
```

Comment: There are multiple things to fix / improve all around this sample code. But first of all, is your JS script in the same HTML file or is it in some .js file apart?

Comment: @revliscano  it is in the same html file, I separated it here so it can look more ordered

Comment: @revliscano What should I fix here?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `NoReverseMatch` exception because you're not using the `{% url &}` tag properly inside the `$.ajax()` function. Since you have that JavaScript code within the HTML itself, then you can replace what you have with the following:

```
url: "{% url 'previous' %}"
```

Also, in the `success` property's callback function, you're not using the data you're getting from the view how it is supposed to be used. Note that you won't be able to get that data using the Django template language inside this callback, but you need to use JavaScript to access that data. For example:

```js
success: function(data){
    console.log(data.req_bio);
}
```

That is because when the HTML gets rendered by Django, the information that you might want to use inside the callback function (e. g.: `{{ req.bio }}`), will not be *there* yet.

Nevertheless, there's a way to keep using the Django template language when handling an AJAX response, using the context data returned by the view. Please, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62490347/7303434) for further information.

Comment: So I should have  console.log(data.req_bio), and console.log(data.req_image) right? What about the user.username and profile_pic?

Comment: The `console.log()` was just to illustrate how you would access the data coming from the template. As regards to the other information, since it is not coming directly from the view that handles the AJAX request, you might want to pass it to the JavaScript function that performs the call and then use that data within the success property's function.

Comment: Nevertheless, in this particular case, since you have your JS within the HTML itself and you want to use information in your success property's function that is available when the HTML is rendered by Django, I think you might use the template language (as you have it) and it would still work. But it is not a very clean approach, I'm afraid.